# Trying to merge citations in word, but instead of (Gurven, 2004; Marshall, 1961) I get (Gurven, 2004 (Marshall, 1961))

Tags: microsoft-word, citations

I am trying to use Word's citation manager to insert citations into my document. I have a sentence which requires two citations, (Gurven, 2004) and (Marshall, 1961).

To be proper APA style, I need it to output (Gurven, 2004; Marshall, 1961). Looking online, I see instructions which simply say to first insert (Gurven, 2004), then put the cursor between "4" and ")" and insert the second citation. However, when I do this, I get  (Gurven, 2004 (Marshall, 1961)).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. Document was originally a .doc. Needed to be saved as a .docx and converted from compatibility mode.